# Why does pint need a unit registry?

Tags: python, pint

The default example for pint is

```
>>> import pint
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>>> 3 * ureg.meter + 4 * ureg.cm
<Quantity(3.04, 'meter')>
```

which makes me wonder what I need the unit registry object for. For example, I could imagine it to be just a submodule:

```
>>> from pint import ureg
>>> 3 * ureg.meter + 4 * ureg.cm
<Quantity(3.04, 'meter')>
```

What is the advantage of ureg being an object instead of a submodule?

**Do I have to share this ureg object or can I simply create a new one when I make multiple calls in different functions?** Or is it possibly a singleton, so it doesn't matter as there will always just be one?

Comment: The tutorial touches on this. You can have multiple registries, each with their own units defined. It explicitly warns against something like `10 * UnitRegistry().meter + 10 * UnitRegistry().meter`; only units from the same registry should be considered compatible. Unfortunately, the tutorial (and the documentation as a whole) seems to lack a good example of why you might want or need a registry other than the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unit registry defines and handles units for you. You could define other units/conversions in your registry so there is no universal registry, there is just one base registry which you can extend.

On how to extent see the section on [Defining units](http://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/defining.html#defining)